# How to use SqlDataReader with a parametrized query in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader, parameterized-query

I'm looking at parameterized query questions I could not find an example of using `SqlDataReader` with a parameterized query to populate a drop down list.

Right now I can populate my drop down just fine using my code here

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString))
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand go = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();

        con.Open();
        go.Connection = con;
        go.CommandText = "SELECT InsuredID, FirstName, LastName FROM [Lab2].[dbo].[INSURED]";
        go.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlDataReader readIn = go.ExecuteReader();

        while (readIn.Read())
        {
            ddlHomeInsuredID.Items.Add(
                new ListItem(readIn["InsuredID"].ToString() + " : " + readIn["FirstName"].ToString()
                + " " + readIn["LastName"].ToString()));
        }

        con.Close();

        ddlHomeInsuredID.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select InsuredID--", "0"));
    }
}
```

However, I want to make this select statement parameterized. How can I do this?
I am comfortable writing parameterized insert statements like the following:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

    command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [Lab2].[dbo].[INSURED] ([FirstName], [LastName], [MI], [DateOfBirth], 
[CreditScore], [AddressID], [DriversLicenseNumber], [LastUpdatedBy], [LastUpdated]) VALUES
(@firstName, @lastName, @middleInitial, @dateOfBirth, @creditScore, @addressID,
@driversLicenseNumber, @lastUpdatedBy, @lastUpdated)";

    command.Parameters.Add("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = Insured.insuredArr[j].getFirstName();
    command.Parameters.Add("@lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = Insured.insuredArr[j].getLastName();
    command.Parameters.Add("@middleInitial", SqlDbType.Char, 1).Value = Insured.insuredArr[j].getMiddleInitial();
    command.Parameters.Add("@dateOfBirth", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = Insured.insuredArr[j].getDateOfBirth();
    command.Parameters.Add("@creditScore", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Insured.insuredArr[j].getCreditScore();
    command.Parameters.Add("@addressID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Insured.insuredArr[j].getAddressID();
    command.Parameters.Add("@driversLicenseNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = Insured.insuredArr[j].getDriversLicenseNumber();
    command.Parameters.Add("@lastUpdatedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = Insured.insuredArr[j].getLastUpdatedBy();
    command.Parameters.Add("@lastUpdated", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Insured.insuredArr[j].getLastUpdated();

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}

MsgBox("Record(s) inserted into database", this.Page, this);
```

So, how can I make my first query like the second example?

Thanks

nammrick

Comment: I'm not sure but I could probabky work it out by googling... are you sure you should have `go.ExecuteNonQuery();` line in there - I don't think it's doing anything in this case.

Comment: Here's an example under "Execute SQL Query with Filter Condition": https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Parameterized-Queries-ADO.Net.aspx

Comment: Yeah that executes the select statement

Comment: ... so does `go.ExecuteReader();` on the next line right? Why execute it twice?

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` is not meant to execute a select statement. Otherwise, you'd actually be doing a query. It's for a statement which output you don't care about.

Comment: You can use parameterized query in `SELECT` statements if containing `WHERE` conditional clause, e.g. `SELECT InsuredID, FirstName, LastName FROM [Lab2].[dbo].[INSURED] WHERE InsuredID = @InsuredID`. From your example, the `WHERE` clause is not exist & the query string just fine, but you need to remove `go.ExecuteNonQuery();` when using `SELECT` (it uses `go.ExecuteReader()` only).

Comment: how come you are using insert query in second example and at same time you want to populate data into list!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, the usage of [`ExecuteNonQuery()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) method isn't valid for `SELECT` query, just stick with [`ExecuteReader()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader(v=vs.110).aspx) since you want to return query results. This is the usage description of `ExecuteNonQuery` method:

> You can use the ExecuteNonQuery to perform catalog operations (for
>   example, querying the structure of a database or creating database
>   objects such as tables), or to change the data in a database without
>   using a DataSet by executing **UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements**.

The modified query flow should be like this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand go = new SqlCommand();

    con.Open();
    go.Connection = con;
    go.CommandText = "SELECT InsuredID, FirstName, LastName FROM [Lab2].[dbo].[INSURED]";

    SqlDataReader readIn = go.ExecuteReader();
    while (readIn.Read())
    {
       // reading data from reader
    }

    con.Close();

    // other stuff
}
```

If you want to use parameterized query for `SELECT` statement, you need at least one column (and one parameter name) to be included in `WHERE` clause (see example below):

```
SELECT InsuredID, FirstName, LastName FROM [Lab2].[dbo].[INSURED] WHERE InsuredID = @InsuredID
```

Then, you can use `SqlParameter` to pass parameter value into the query above:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString))
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand go = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();

    con.Open();
    go.Connection = con;
    go.CommandText = "SELECT InsuredID, FirstName, LastName FROM [Lab2].[dbo].[INSURED] WHERE InsuredID = @InsuredID";
    go.Parameters.Add("@InsuredID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1; // example value for parameter passing

    SqlDataReader readIn = go.ExecuteReader();
    while (readIn.Read())
    {
       // reading data from reader
    }

    con.Close();

    // other stuff
}
```

NB: Avoid perform `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` operation at the same time with populating data by `SELECT` statement with same active connection, the previous connection should be closed first before executing another query.

More examples:

[How to use string variable in sql statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263893/how-to-use-string-variable-in-sql-statement)

[How to use sql parameters for a select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291417/how-to-use-sql-parameters-for-a-select-query)

Comment: No need to call `con.Close()` as the `using` statement will take care of closing for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18588084/4762482