# Parametrized query with Snowflake and pass the values from Snowflake .NET Connector

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Create parameterize with Snowflake as like MySQL and SQL Server. Need to pass the values from .NET Snowflake .NET Connector.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/

Query with value:

```
select * 
from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"."WEB_SITE" 
where ((Web_REC_START_DATE is null and IFF('2000-08-16' is null,true,false))    
       or Web_REC_START_DATE > '2000-08-16')
```

[How to use SqlDataReader with a parametrized query in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577260/how-to-use-sqldatareader-with-a-parametrized-query-in-c/46577561)

Query with names of parameters:

```
select * 
from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"."WEB_SITE" 
where ((Web_REC_START_DATE is null and IFF(@StartDate is null,true,false)) 
       or Web_REC_START_DATE > @StartDate)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the snowflake .net connector, is hosted in [github](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net), and it's read me describes how to in the [bind-parameter](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net#bind-parameter) section

so looking at the tests in the code, specifically the [BindTest line 75](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/blob/master/Snowflake.Data.Tests/SFBindTestIT.cs#L75)

it shows named parameters being used. thus:

```
command.CommandText = "insert into TEST_TBL values(:p0)";
var param = command.CreateParameter();
param.ParameterName = "p0";
param.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32;
param.Value = DBNull.Value;
command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: I want to create the query with named parameters as like query supported in MySQL and MS SQL.