# Parameterized Query for dynamic SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are using snowflake client nuget package and creating dynamic queries as below:

```
   using Snowflake.Client;

   using (var conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
   {
       conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
       conn.Open();

       var cmd = new SnowflakeDbCommand(conn);
       cmd.CommandText = $"select count(*) from {tableName}";
       //other code goes here
   }
```

We are using the above code but our sonar keeps flagging the dynamic SQL query as below:

> Make sure using a dynamically formatted SQL query is safe here.

We have tried using parameter as mentioned here:

[Parametrized query with Snowflake and pass the values from Snowflake .NET Connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66633573/parametrized-query-with-snowflake-and-pass-the-values-from-snowflake-net-connec)

But with this the command fails as null.

We have also tried using string.format as:

```
string.Format("select count(*) from \"{0}\"", tableName);
```

But this one still is flagged by sonar.

If anyone can provide any other suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: You can't parameterize a table name. You need to either whitelist or correctly escape the name.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't parameterize the table name. Typically, to ensure safety, a query is first made to the platform's equivalent of the information schema, to ensure a valid table name is provided. Then the result returned from the query, rather than the original user-supplied string, is used to build the dynamic SQL, possibly in conjunction with something like QUOTENAME().

Comment: @Charlieface how can I escape it. I tried using string.format for that but it dint work out

Comment: According to the docs, surround it in double quotes `"name"` and duplicate all double quotes inside the name. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax So `"\"" + tableName.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\""`

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in SQL and Python, but not .NET. So your mileage may vary.

I typically, create a variable outside the initial SQL call, when I am unable to do a string replacement.

```
   using Snowflake.Client;
   
   var sqlCall = "select count(*) from \"" + tableName + "\"";

   using (var conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
   {
       conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
       conn.Open();

       var cmd = new SnowflakeDbCommand(conn);
       cmd.CommandText = sqlCall;
       //other code goes here
   }
```

This has typically worked well for me. What you should watch out for is the number of double quotes that appear in your query string before being submitted to cmd.CommandText.